# CallbackHandler in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise

I have the following method in a .js file for an asynchronous network connection

```
function requestWatsonDiscovery(queryString) {
    console.log('Query =', queryString);
    if (typeof queryString !== 'undefined') {
        var discoveryUrl = `something`
        console.log('Total url =', discoveryUrl);
        var options = {
            host: 'gateway.watsonplatform.net',
            path: discoveryUrl,
            auth: auth
        };

        http.get(options, function(http_res) {
            // initialize the container for our data
            var data = "";

            // this event fires many times, each time collecting another piece of the response
            http_res.on("data", function(chunk) {
                // append this chunk to our growing `data` var
                //console.log(data);
                data += chunk;
            });

            // this event fires *one* time, after all the `data` events/chunks have been gathered
            http_res.on("end", function() {
                // you can use res.send instead of console.log to output via express
                //console.log(data);
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                watsonReturnedText = parseData(data);
                //console.log(watsonReturnedText);
                //returnResult();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

at the same time I am updating my UI in another .js file.I want to get notified when the above asynchronous method has completed. I understand I can use callbacks /promises to do it.Can you show me the syntax to write a promise or a call back.

Comment: use RSVP for promises.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that please. I am new to javascript programming

Comment: use Promises for promises since node has native promises

Comment: should be `.once('end')` rather than `on('end')` if you want to prevent memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, this should give you basic understanding of callback in your demo

```
function requestWatsonDiscovery (queryString, callback){ // <- new param
    http.get(options, function (http_res) {
        var data = "";

        http_res.on("data", function (chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });
        http_res.on("end", function () {
            var parseData =JSON.parse(data);
            callback(parseData); // <- usage of new param
        }); 
    });
}

requestWatsonDiscovery(null, function(result) {
    // result is your data;
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: better use promises than callback

Comment: @F.bernal agree, but the simplest solution for OP will be callback, as he is a beginner, promises require a bit more knowledge imho

Comment: Can you suggest me some links where I can learn about promises.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score -1):

This is basically..

```
function requestWatsonDiscovery (queryString){
  return new RSVP.promise((resolve, reject) => {

    if (typeof queryString !== 'undefined') {
      var discoveryUrl = `something`

      var options = {
        host: 'gateway.watsonplatform.net',
        path: discoveryUrl,
        auth : auth
      };

      http.get(options, function (http_res) {
        var data = "";

        http_res.on("data", function (chunk) {
          data += chunk;
        });

        http_res.on("end", function () {
          data =JSON.parse(data);
          watsonReturnedText = parseData(data);
          resolve(watsonReturnedText);
        });
      });
    }
    else { reject(); }
  }); //end promise
}
```

When you call your requestWatsonDiscovery do this...

```
var watsonPromise = requestWatsonDiscovery(queryString);

watsonPromise.then((data) => { 
 //use your watson data
}).catch(() => {
 //manage the error
});
```

Comment: why use a promise library when all you need is stock standard Promise/A+ promises that are available natively in node? even https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise (which is rsvp boiled down to ES6 promises) is preferable, as the code doesn't require any rsvp so called "toys"

Comment: I understand you are saying -RSVP library is unnecessary because node supports this natively.Could you post a syntax which will help me do it.

Comment: What is RSVP? -1

Comment: Use native or library... but use it ;) The solution is valid.